# Flutter: Remove all the routes [screens] below current one

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator

I want to remove all the routes or 'screens' under the current one in the Navigator Stack

so if I have [Page1 => Page2 => Page3 => Page4] I want to keep Page 4 only

how can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that with `removeRouteBelow` method ,
just add this code :

```
if(!ModalRoute.of(context).isFirst)
Navigator.of(context).removeRouteBelow(ModalRoute.of(context));
```